# How to overlapping report items in BIRT?

Tags: report, birt

For some reason I need to overlap 2 report elements in BIRT. For example I need to put 2 labels one on top of another. Is this possible in BIRT? I am using BIRT 4.3. Normally when we place elements in report designer each item is occupying one full row. Some times i need to overlap elements and sometimes i need to place elements side by side. side by side can be achieved with Grid but I am not sure how to overlap report items? Please help and thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I edited to add the image from the link OP supplied in the comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put two labels in the same cell of a graph or table, then define when to "hide element" with the "Visibility" property.

OR

In order to have both display at the same time, you can use a grid to define where the top label will go, then add the back label as an image using the background (advanced property)

[image]

Comment: No the requirement is to display both. not one at a time. It is to create some some effect like in html. check the following url so that you can understand what i am trying to do.    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B59LVhKQaKQYdXB2T1pNbWxhQ0k/edit?usp=drive_web

Comment: @muralidhar, Edited to show one way.  In this case I used an image for the back label.